# Make this RegEx work in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex, srt

I need to get the data of an SRT file as an array using a regex.

Here is my code so far:

**Javacript:**

```
function readSrt() {
  var srtUrl = 'assets/media/subtitles.srt';

  $.get(srtUrl, function(data) {
    console.log("SRT:", data); // it reads ok

    var regexp = /(.*)\n(.*),\d\d\d --> (.*)\n(.*)/g; // this regex doesn't work

    console.log("SUBS:", data.match(regexp)); // outputs null
  });
}
```

**subtitles.srt:**

```
0
00:00:00,000 --> 00:00:01,000
Instructor…All right, let's start off

1
00:00:01,000 --> 00:00:04,000
here. We were, I think, wrapping up kind

...

14
00:00:40,000 --> 00:00:42,000
mound, basically.

15
00:00:42,000 --> 00:00:44,000
If you go to Colossae today, none of it

...
```

Need to get:

```
1.  0
2.  00:00:00
3.  00:00:01,000
4.  Instructor…All right, let's start off
```

Did several attempts in [regex101.com](http://regex101.com/) but only seems to work well with PHP but not javascript.

What am I doing wrong and how do I fix it?

Comment: What do you mean by "doesnt work?"

Comment: give https://www.debuggex.com/ a go and see where it breaks down.

Comment: The global flag is going to give you trouble. Even if you get a correct regex you won't be able to extract the capturing groups. You'd have to use `exec` and loop, or use `replace` with a callback to access the groups.

Comment: Try using `(.*?)` instead.

Comment: for those recommending any for of `.*`: The dot wildcard does not match newlines in JavaScript regular expression handling, and there is no pattern modifier to force it to. Matching across newlines requires explicit [^\n]+ groups

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing that might be wrong in your regex is that `.*` is greedy. It will start to match in the first caption and only end the match at the last caption. Try replacing it with its lazy alternative, to match as little as possible each time.

```
/(.*?)\n(.*?),\d\d\d --> (.*?)\n(.*?)\n/
```

Answer (score 0):

You're relying on the `.` wildcard character to also catch `\n` (and presumably `\r`), which it won't do (see http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html for the info on that, "There is indeed no /s modifier" bit). Use explicit groups instead for greater win: use `[^\n]+\n` for "anything and then a newline instead, `[^,]+,` for "anything before the comma", etc.

Answer (score 0):

You're close. The main problem with your regex is the part around `(.*),\d\d\d`, which doesn't work because `(.*)` will match the entire line of text, making the rest of the regex invalid.

The fixed regex is:

```
/(.*)\n([^,]+),[\d]{3} --> (.*)\n(.*)(?:\n*)/g
```